# How can I make my mysql getting one record per month query faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a big database with about 3 million records with records containing a time stamp.

Now I want to select one record per month and it works using this query:

```
SELECT timestamp, id, gas_used, kwh_used1, kwh_used2 FROM energy 
GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

It works but it is very slow.

I have indexes on `id` and on `timestamp`.

What can I do to make this query fast?

Comment: why you want to get all the records in single shot? Filter data to get limited records at a time

Comment: Do you have two different indexes or one combined on both values ?

Comment: @Christophe I have a unique index for id and a unique index for timestamp

Comment: @Code-Monk maybe I could use a limit to get 1 result at the time maybe select only by one date at the time

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp)` is forcing the engine to look at each record individually, aka a sequential scan, which obviously is very slow when you have 30M records.

A common solution is to add an indexed column with just the criterium you will want to select on.  However, I highly suspect that you will actually want to select on Year-Month, if your db is not reset every year.

To avoid data corruption issues, it may be best to create an insert trigger that automatically fills that field. That way this extra column doesn't interfere with your business logic.

Comment: So it would have been beter if i had created the colums year month day hour minute second seperately instead of using timestamp field?

Comment: I'm not a fan of storing dates that way, just leave it as a timestamp, that will make most other processing a lot easier and more natural.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to SELECT columns that don't appear in GROUP BY statement, unless they are handled with aggregating function such as MIN(), MAX(), SUM() etc.

In your query this applies to columns:

```
id, gas_used, kwh_used1, kwh_used2
```

You will not get the "earliest" (by timestamp) row for each month in this case.

More:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Ok, thanx, that explains.